# Retrieving GUI Objects from another process

Tags: c++, windows, code-injection

I want to retrieve a GUI Object so that I can read and modify they Object.
Right now the only way I can think of to do this is via injection (where the injection does a lot of the retrieving of the data and sends back what I want). My problem with injection is that I cannot easily debug it and it takes a long time to figure out what to do.

I can find the handle of the GUI object so is there a way i can use ReadProcessMemory() or something like this so that I can read the memory in another process and from this build it up into the GUI object that I want?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the proper permissions and have some way to obtain the window handle (`HWND`) of a specific GUI object (see [`FindWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), you can call regular Win32 API functions such as [`SetWindowText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to modify the contents of those GUI objects.

**However, doing this can break the other process' logic!**  If the process that owns the GUI object has cached some information and you modify the source behind its back, you might not get the desired effect.

Comment: SetWindowText only works for GUI Objects in the same application? Also I cannot read all the information that I need using this. For example I cannot get the list of items in a combo box

Comment: @user1227708: Send `WM_SETTEXT` directly to modify the text in another program.  In terms of reading the ComboBox contents, you need to get its handle through `FindWindowEx` (use the class name to get it). After that, as far as I'm aware there are no interprocess limitations to using the regular ComboBox macros and messages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user1227708: You might need to send the message explicitly using [`PostMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx)  or [`PostThreadMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx).